# In Delphi method signatures, why can't Generics be combined with arrays?

Tags: delphi, generics, method-signature

While attempting to revise one of my records to use Generics, I discovered that combining Generics and arrays within one of the methods' signatures produces an error:

> Type [type] is not yet completely defined

I have two minimal examples. The first is for parameter types:

```
  TRec1 = record
    procedure DoFooList(A: TArray<TRec1>);
  end;

  TGeneRec1<T> = record
    procedure DoFoo(G: TGeneRec1<T>);
    procedure DoFooList(A: TArray<TGeneRec1<T>>); // This causes an error.
  end;
```

The second is for return types:

```
  TRec2 = record
    function ReturnFooList: TArray<TRec2>;
  end;

  TGeneRec2<T> = record
    function ReturnFoo: TGeneRec2<T>;
    function ReturnFooList: TArray<TGeneRec2<T>>; // This causes an error.
  end;
```

In each example, each type within a method's signature can involve an array or a Generic, but not both.

My have a few questions about this phenomenon:

- Is there a technical reason why combining these features is impossible?
- If not, then have the developers explained why it is unsupported?
- Why is the error characterized as "not yet completely defined"? (That's not a sufficient condition for the error; it's true regardless of whether the type is Generic and regardless of whether it's an array.)
- Is there a way to circumvent this restriction?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know yet what type `T` is at the point where it needs to define a dynamic array that is based on `T`. Dynamic arrays are managed types, and they have RTTI associated with them since the compiler needs to know how to handle the elements when the array is copied or destroyed.

Comment: That's how it would work:
`TGeneRec1<T> = record
    procedure DoFoo(G: TGeneRec1<T>);
    procedure DoFooList(A: array of TGeneRec1<T>);
  end;`

Answer (score 0):

the generics type is prepared during compiling .
when the compiler arrive at DoFooList generate a DoFooList function for every type used in the code with this record.
cannot prepare a function with undefined type . should be everything defined at moment of compiling.

```
TGeneRec1<T> = record 
  procedure DoFoo(G: TGeneRec1<T>);
  procedure DoFooList<T1 : record>(A: TArray<T1>); 
end;
```

will work if use it like this :

```
procedure example
var 
  lExVar : TGeneRec1<Type>; 
  lExArr : TArray<TGeneRec1<Type>>
begin
  lExVar.DoFooList<TGeneRec1<Type>>(lExArr );   
end;
```